# Executing PHP file with Windows server 2008 Scheduled Task

Tags: php, cron, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

i know there are a lot of posts about scheduled task and a fair few about executing PHP files but i have looked and tried to figure it out but still coming up short.

I am still learning a lot of the ways of Windows server so please, if something needs to be pointed out let me know.

So i set up a scheduled task that would execute at 1am and in all fairness this worked a charm, however i didn't realise that it would just open the file in notepad (Because that is the application that php files are associated with).

So i did my research and found a lot people saying that i needed to pass the php.exe file in with it, these people were also providing i add this to the task:

```
C:\Path\to\php.exe -f "C:\Path\to\file.php"
```

So i put it in the action tab like so. please note that there is an error in the screen shot, i forgot to put \php.exe at the end of the sting.
[image: Screen shot of New task widnow]

When i click OK i get asked this

[image: Screen shot after clicking OK]

As you can see from the picture it only lists "C:\Program"

I've tried moving things around and had nothing, i've tried wrapping the first part in quotes as well.

So can someone tell me what i need to do or what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP` is a *directory*, not an *application*. Put `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe"` in the "Program" box, and `-f "C:\Path\to\file.php"` in the Arguments box. Might want to also set "Start in" to `"C:\Path\to\"` (without the actual filename of the target script, just the path to it).

Comment: @DCoder Thanks for pointing this out, it was a mistake i left in the screen shot, i have updated the post to make people aware of this. I have set it up like you have suggested but now it doesn't seem to execute the code properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the path contains spaces, then wrap it in quotes

```
"C:\Path\to\php.exe" -f "C:\Path\to\file.php"
```

the same way you do with the file to execute

Comment: I haven't tried putting quotes around both paths and no the -f.... Will give that a go now.

Comment: Also, what does the -f do?

Comment: -f tells PHP that the next argument is going to be the filename of a php script to execute (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php for details)

Comment: Hey, i've just tried this and it says it runs successfully but it seems like my script is not being executed. The script sends and email out with PHP mailer, now i insert a record to the database at the start of the script to see if it was executing anything at all and nothing was inserted to the database. I further tested this by running the script through a browser and it works just fine. Any ideas? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: That's dependent on your code, but watch out for little things like the directory your script is running in

Comment: @MarkBaker, Isn't `-f` optional?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the whole thing in quotes fine. I would recommend using php.exe and not just php.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe -f c:\inetpub\cron\test.php"
```